# XPages loading time in the Firefox with richtext

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

i created an XPage with an richtext editor an an datepicker.
When i open documents with this XPage and change from the read to the edit mode. It will takes (without cache) 5-10 secconds to load (chrome just take 0,5 secconds).

The problem is as you can see, it will load a lot of dojo ressources.
It only happends while the richtext editor or/and the datepicker are in the XPage.

Is there a way to tell the domino server to send the dojo lib as one compressed file?
Or is there another solution to solve this problem.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
the property `xsp.resources.aggregate=true` does not work for this problem.

[image: Firebug delais]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the problem. It will only cause if the editbutton makes a partial update on a panel with a document and a richtext editor inside. If i make a full refresh it will load the compressed files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "*Use runtime optimized javascript and CSS ressources*". This option can be found on the *Application Properties*, Section "*XPages*". This will add the parameter

```
xsp.resources.aggregate=true
```

to your *xsp.properties* file and enables the feature for you whole application.

Alternativly you can enable this feature for one XPage only by adding this lines to the XPages source code:

```
<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter name="xsp.resources.aggregate" value="true" />
</xp:this.properties>
```

Comment: thanks.. i use that already and it works for my script libraries but not for dojo framework files from the server that are used for the richtext editor

Comment: In the screenshot it does not look like that the feature is enabled. Is this a 8.5.3 server?

Comment: yes, it is a 8.5.3 server and the parameter xsp.resources.aggregate=true is set. Additional i try the <xp:parameter name="xsp.resources.aggregate" value="true" /> with the same result

Comment: Oh, Sorry. You are right. But I think that this is not a Domino specific issue: The requests are made by the browser and depend on the elements used by CKEditor. This cannot aggregated on the serverside, because the Server has no crystal ball... The question is if there is a "Full" package for CKEditor available containing all components in just a few Files.

Comment: that means, any one else has the same problem with the firefox? i can't believe that.

Comment: I still think that there is something wrong on your server: I cannot see a URL like this one in your screenshot: *http://localhost/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.de-de/@In.js*. The *@In.js* file is the CKEditor widget in the minimized version. In your screenshot, the widget is still loaded "the normal" way without minimizing. Same the other ressources on your XPage. No "@" files -> no minimization. Please check your server / application config.

Comment: i tried it on different servers with the same result. He will load a MYSERVER/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.de-de/@Iq.js when i open the page. After that i clear the consol to see what he will load when i switch to the edit mode.

Comment: finally i found the problem. It will only cause if the editbutton makes a partial update on a panel with a document and a richtext editor inside. If i make a full refresh it will load the compressed files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, Ok. The mystery is solved. Could you please add this as a new answer to your question and set this to "solved"? Perhaps this will helps other users. Thanks in advance!